# Template CSS insert overriding primary CSS

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I'm trying to modify [this template](https://codepen.io/shaneheyns/pen/OPWGry) for my site. It defines rules for the `html`, `body`, and list elements that override my site CSS (which I don't want). I can modify a couple of things without too much trouble, but I can't seem to get around swapping the `html { font-size: 62.5% }` into the `pricing-wrapper` or `pricing-body` div elements; the text size becomes distorted.

I think I'm doing something wrong here... I've tried adding classes to the `ul` and `li` elements like `.pricing-body ul, li` but that is not working as well as I hoped.

**QUESTION: Best way to preserve the formatting of the table while separating it from the rest of parent page's styling?**

**UPDATE:** For instance, if I comment out the `html` tag on Line 52, the template falls apart. I've tried moving the `font-size: 62.5%` to other divs in the pricing container, but no luck.

Comment: So far I've only been modifying the CSS only, not JavaScript or HTML. I'm not so familiar with JS, so if there is stuff in there I need to modify to keep the effects identical, please let me know.

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: The template I linked to defines properties for `html` and `body` which are page wide. Removing these, or modifying them, or putting their properties into some of the child divs is not working. The question in bold should be clear enough. I can elaborate further if you need, please tell me what is still unclear.

Comment: Have you tried !important  keyword ?

Comment: I'm not sure where I would apply the !important keyword and what it would do. I will look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From that you can safely remove down to line 72 in the CSS. That's just a reset then some base styles.

Comment: You mean remove Lines 1-72? Not sure that will work... If you _just_ comment out the `html` element on Line 52, the whole template falls apart.

Comment: When you add that to your own css you can remove the 1-72

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are talking about. The styles are in two separate files. Can you give an example with code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One nice thing about CSS is that it allows you to redefine styles farther down. In other words, if your CSS repeats the styling for the same ID / class / element in two places (with conflicting styles) the latest style over-rules the earlier style.

So, for example:

```
#bob {width:50%;}
#bob {width:75%;}
```

will leave the element with `id="bob"` styled at 75%.

Therefore, move to the bottom of the stylesheet and add your own styling, and you will over-ride the template styling.

Also, if you are defining your own styles in a separate stylesheet, make sure that your stylesheet is added to the HTML ***after*** the template stylesheet, so that your styling is the latest/final styling.

Comment: Thanks @cssyphus. I have these styles separated into a different file. In my document head I've tried loading the main css _after_ the pricing table file, but this didn't work. The problem is the author of the snippet designed this to be affect the entire page... try it yourself: take the snippet and put it into a webpage of yours and try to keep the original webpage styling while also keeping the formatting of the pricing table (font/margins/padding).